# Deleted files from Macintosh HD still take up space

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, storage

I just deleted about 50GB of files from my Mac's onboard storage, however it only resulted in the removal of about 8GB.

What happened and how can I fix this?

Comment: How did you delete them?

Comment: @Mark, trash 15

Answer (score -2):

It's called [local snapshots](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204015) which works as a backup, if you are low in space the OS will automatically delete the stuff.